# Constructing the Lebesgue measure on the reals.

Tags: measure-theory

So far, we have only constructed the Lebesgue measure on intervals.
Now if $\{I_k\}$ is a countable cover of the reals by intervals which overlap at one point at most, we say that $S\subset \mathbb R$ is measurable iff $S \cap I_k $ is measurable in $I_k$ for all $k$ and set $$m(S)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}m_{I_k}(S\cap I_k)$$
I have shown that the values coincide for any two covers, knowing that $S$ is measurable for all elements in both covers. How do we show that if S is measurable according to one cover, then it is measurable according to another? (Then showing that the family of measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra and additivity of the measure should pose little problem.)

Comment: For two covers $\{I_k\}$ and $\{J_l\}$, use their intersections $\{I_k\cap J_l\}$, so that $I_k=\bigcup_l (I_k\cap J_l)$ and $J_l=\bigcup_k (I_k\cap J_l)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$S\cap I_k$ measurable in $I_k$"? You say you've defined measure only for intervals but the intersection isn't always an interval

Comment: We have constructed the Lebesgue measure on an interval. Not only subintevals are measurable.

Comment: @Berci Your suggestion is sound to show that the measure of a subset does not depend on the cover, given it is measurable according to both covers. If you read the question carefully, you will notice that this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show that if $I\subset J$ and $S\cap I$ is measurable in $I$ then $S\cap I$ is measurable in $J$. Then given any two covers you can reduce them to a common subcover.

Comment: Yes, that is the result I'm trying to get. How can I show that $S\cap I$ is measurable in $J$.

Comment: How is defined measurability on an interval?

Comment: $S \subset I$ is measurable $\Leftrightarrow I \setminus S$ is measurable $\Leftrightarrow m_\star(S)=m^\star(S) \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon >0)(\exists U \quad open)(\exists K \quad compact)(K \subset S \subset U \land m(U\setminus K)<\epsilon)$

Comment: As you can see the definition does not depend on the interval

Comment: I am still not convinced. If we take the second definition with the inner and outer measures, the supremum will get smaller, and the infimum will get bigger, hence we can only establish an inequality. If we take the third, what is to guarantee that such open and compact sets exist not only in I but in J as well?

Comment: Here you should check whether when you say "U open" and "K compact" you mean open and compact in the whole set of reals number or in the interval I you are considering. I think that your book means in the whole set of real numbers. In that case if a set $S$ is contained in two different intervals $I$ and $J$, there will be no difference in its measure or measurability.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not specified. I always assumed U, K are subsets of the interval. Well K is a subset of S so there is nothing to prove, but U the open set is not.

Comment: Suppose instead that they are subset of the whole real line. At the end the results are the same, but this way it is easier to get them.

Comment: I had a better look at the definition of $m^*$. It's not dependent on the interval. Now $m_*(S)=sup\{m^*(K): K \subset S \quad is \quad compact\}$ is a theorem. q.e.d.